# Accessing RS232 Rx Tx instead of OTG on stellaris LM4F232H5QD evaluation board

Tags: uart, rs232, texas-instruments, stellaris

I am asking two related questions here:

1. I can see a program uart_echo for [stellaris lm4f232h5qd](http://www.ti.com/tool/ek-lm4f232) . What I want is that  I need to access this data on teraterminal using PA1 and PA2 pins instead of OTG.  I have a [RS232 to USB](http://www.amazon.in/Upgrade-PL2303HX-Converter-Adapter-Arduino/dp/B00MYYD5OS) converter that I connected to PA1 and PA0.

PA0 is connected to the Rx of the converter  and PA1 is connected to the Tx of the converter. The Vcc of the converter I connected to 3.3V pin  adjacent to PA7 (near temperature sensor). I connected  the ground of the converter to the GND pin on the same row where PA7 is located

The board is powered by a 3.7V battery. The +VBUS is connected to + terminal of the battery and the negative connected to GND pin near the SD card.

Then I plugged the  USB end of the converter to the laptop,, and the smoke started coming from the converter!

The converted is useless now but fortunately the board is not having any issues.

Where did I made mistake in the above connection?

What is the correct procedure to access PA0 and PA1 pins of the board?

2. I want to get the Accelerometer data on the teraterminal.  There is a pin on the board Ax, Ay, Az. I checked using a multimeter that if I move the board the values changes.

How do I get this data on the teraterminal?

Kindly help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

1. PA0 on your LM4F232 eval board is U0RX, that is, it receive data from others; PA1 is U0TX, that is, it transmit data to others. So you should connect your converters Rx to PA1, and Tx to PA0. It seems you mistake them.
   **Note:** It seems the PA0 and PA1 have connections to the on board ICDI, check if there are jumpers to break the connections before connecting your converter.
2. Ax, Ay, and Az is the buffered Accelerometer BM140's Ax, Ay, Az analogue output. You can connect them to the ADC input of the MCU (already on your eval board, so you don't need buy new ones). Their may have jumps to configure this.

All the needed information can be fund in the [user manual](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu272/spmu272.pdf) of the eval board.